# Write image on the fly with javascript to iframe

Tags: javascript, activex, dhtml

I have an Activex who return a jpg image as an array of bytes, I want to show the image inside an iframe.

```
    function showImage(){
       var iscanner = document.getElementById("MyActivex");
       binaryData = iscanner.Image();
       window.frames['myiframe'].document.open("image/jpeg");
       window.frames['myiframe'].document.binarywrite(binaryData);
       window.frames['myiframe'].document.close();
    }
```

but I have problems with the open, explorer said "is not a valid argument"  :(

```
  window.frames['myiframe'].document.open("image/jpeg");
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536652%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the only MIME type supported by the `document.open()` method is `text/html`